# Graphql mutation with parent object and array of children on aws-appsync

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I got a graphql mutation that passes a parent object as well as a list of children like

```
input CreateQuestionWithManyAnswersInput {
    question: CreateQuestionInput!
    answers: [CreateAnswerInput!]!
}
```

The actual types are pretty boring, an ID, some strings, etc.

I have attached a pipeline resolver to the mutation in appsync but I'm don't know how to write the individual request and response mapping templates.

So far I got this for the createQuestion function:

**Request mapping template:**

```
{
    "operation": "PutItem",
    "key": {
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.question.id),
    },
    "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args.input.question)
}
```

**Response mapping template:**

```
$util.qr($ctx.stash.put("question", $util.toJson($ctx.result)))
$util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

For the create answersFunction I got:

**Request mapping template:**

```
#set($answersdata = [])
#foreach($item in ${ctx.args.input.answers})
    $util.qr($answersdata.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($item)))
#end

{
    "operation" : "BatchPutItem",
    "tables" : {
        "Answer-ium2s7hanfgl3dwbamwgloetsi-dev": $utils.toJson($answersdata)
    }
}
```

**Response mapping template:**

```
$util.qr($ctx.stash.put("answers", $util.toJson($ctx.result).items))
$util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

And in the **after mapping template** of the pipeline I got:

```
$util.qr($ctx.result.put("question", $ctx.stash.question))
$util.qr($ctx.result.put("answers", $ctx.stash.question.answers))
$util.toJson($ctx.result)
```

However, this fails with:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createQuestionWithManyAnswers": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createQuestionWithManyAnswers",
        "question",
        "id"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'ID' within parent 'Question' (/createQuestionWithManyAnswers/question/id)"
    },
    {
      "path": [
        "createQuestionWithManyAnswers",
        "question",
        "text"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'String' within parent 'Question' (/createQuestionWithManyAnswers/question/text)"
    },
    {
      "path": [
        "createQuestionWithManyAnswers",
        "answers"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'null' within parent 'QuestionWithManyAnswers' (/createQuestionWithManyAnswers/answers)"
    }
  ]
}
```

**mutation type**

```
type Mutation {
    createQuestionWithManyAnswers(input: CreateQuestionWithManyAnswersInput!): QuestionWithManyAnswers
}
```

**update**
With the help of Tinou I got a little further. Basically my question now boils down to how can I turn the stash into a valid response in the response mapping template?

My log

```
"stash": {
    "answers": [
        {
            "correct": true,
            "id": "0cbc20a3-09dd-44d8-bc7c-e2ce50d8f9b1",
            "text": "a right answer"
        },
        {
            "correct": false,
            "id": "b73b5696-e86b-4ad5-bce4-765234f566df",
            "text": "a wrong answer"
        }
    ],
    "question": {
        "id": "b28b8c22-6cdb-41a1-8697-78a799deed6f",
        "text": "my new title",
        "explanation": "some explanation about this"
    }
}
```

and my response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createQuestionWithManyAnswers": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "createQuestionWithManyAnswers",
        "question"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'Question' within parent 'QuestionWithManyAnswers' (/createQuestionWithManyAnswers/question)"
    },
    {
      "path": [
        "createQuestionWithManyAnswers",
        "answers"
      ],
      "locations": null,
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'null' within parent 'QuestionWithManyAnswers' (/createQuestionWithManyAnswers/answers)"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Mutation type:**

```
type Mutation {
    createQuestionWithManyAnswers(input: CreateQuestionWithManyAnswersInput!): QuestionWithManyAnswers
}
```

**QuestionWithManyAnswers type:**

```
type QuestionWithManyAnswers {
    question: Question!
    answers: [Answer]!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to share your Mutation type along with the other type definitions you are using so we can help you reproduce? What is your pipeline resolver before template?

That said, I see a couple of things that could be problematic, first, your `createQuestion` request mapping template, the util call is missing a `$`:

> "attributeValues" :
>   **$**util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args.input.question)

Also, in your `createAnswersFunction`response mapping template, you are trying to access the `items` property on a json string. The following won't work

> $util.toJson($ctx.result).items

instead you probably meant

```
$util.toJson($ctx.result.items)
```

But that will also not work because the result of the BatchPutItem operation is keyed by table so to get the data from your result, you should do

```
$ctx.result.data.get("Answer-ium2s7hanfgl3dwbamwgloetsi-dev")
```

In general while you are in development, I would suggest you enable the CloudWatch Logs at least at `Error` level. That will give you [field level log information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/monitoring.html#field-level-logs), i.e you will have access to the invocation results, your evaluated mapping templates, the content of the stash and so on. This is helpful for debugging.

Comment: Thx for your comment Tinou. I have updated my question with your suggestions.

Comment: I would advise against using `$ctx.result.put`, and we still don't know what is the output type of your mutation. Also enable CloudWatch logs on your API so you can see the output of the after template.

Comment: I added the types. I would have thought that this is a fairly standard operation. Creating a parent object in table 1 and then creating a number of children in table 2. Is there no working example for this anywhere in the documentation?

The alternative, ie. to do everything on the client in a chain of api calls, is horrible. Also, you say that you would advice against using "put". How else am I supposed to persist data in a pipeline resolver? iirc I lifted that straight out of the documentation?